Global optima of Linear Programming Problems
Consider the problem $P_1$:
$$
\min h(u) = \langle d, u \rangle + b
$$
where $u\in M,$ vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-zero, and  $M$ is a non-empty polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Assume there exists a vertice $ u_0 $ of polyhedron $M$, which has exactly $ k $ adjacent vertices of $M$ $ u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_k $ such that $\langle d, u_0 \rangle \leq \langle d, u_i \rangle$ for all $( i = 1, 2, \ldots, k )$. Prove that $ u_0 $ is an optimal solution of $P_1$.
My attempt at solving this problem:
Let $E = conv(u_0,u_1,u_2,...u_k)$; it is easy to see that $E$ is a convex polyhedron. Consider $x \in E$, then $x$ can be written as a convex combination: $u = \lambda_0 u_0 + \lambda_1 u_1 + … + \lambda_k u_k$, where $ \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 + … + \lambda_k = 1$.
Since this, $h(u) = h(\lambda_0 u_0 + \lambda_1 u_1 + … + \lambda_k u_k) =$ $\langle d, \lambda_0 u_0 + \lambda_1 u_1 + … + \lambda_k u_k \rangle$ $+b \geq \langle d,u_0 \rangle + b = h(u_0) $
$\Rightarrow u_0$ is the $\textbf{global optima}$ over $E$, which is a convex subpolyhedron of $M$. So I wonder whether $u_0$ can be considered as a local optima over $M$, allowing me to apply the property that if $u_0$ is a local optima over a polyhedron, it is also the global optima.
However, after trying, I don’t have a complete solution. Does my approach to prove $u_0$ is a local optima over $M$ seem valid?

First, I guess that the polyhedron $M$ is required to be convex, because it is easy to provide a counterexample  to the claim to prove when $n=2$. So we assume that $M$ is convex. Next, I do not know what definition of an adjacent vertex you use, so based on the geometric intuition we assume that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $u_0$ such that $M\cap U=C\cap U$, where $C$ is the convex cone with the vertex $u_0$ and spanned by the points
$u_1,\dots, u_k$. That is
$$C=u_0+\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i (u_i-u_0):\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k\ge 0\right\}.$$
Then similarly to the proof from the question, we can show that $h(u)\ge h(u_0)$ for each $h\in C$.
It remains to note that $M\subset C$, by the convexity of $M$ and the equality $M\cap U=C\cap U$.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Yes, I believe your approach can be made to work.  If $\ d\ed\min_\limits{1\le i\le k}\big(\|u_0-u_i\|\big)\ ,$ then I'm reasonably sure that
$$
N\left(u_0,\frac{d}{2}\right)\cap M=N\left(u_0,\frac{d}{2}\right)\cap E\ ,\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
so the global optimality of $\ u_0\ $ would imply its local optimality over $\ M\ .$  The identity \eqref{1} requires proof however, and the only approaches  towards proving  it that I can think of appear to be fairly cumbersome.

Sorry, I forgot the condition : " $u_0$ is a vertice of polyhedron $M$ and has $\textbf{exactly}$  $k$  adjacent vertices $u_1,u_2,…,u_k$, such that $⟨d,u_0⟩≤⟨d,u_i⟩$ for all  $(i=1,2,…,k)$. I have edited that in the question. Thank you for commenting !

I've updated my answer in the light of the changes to the question.

Can you describe your approach for proving the idenity (1). Like you, i completely believe in that
